# What does it mean outside of main in "Do not use Eval() outside of the main() "?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm new to roku development and considering using eval but I stumbled upon this warning in the [docs](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Runtime+Functions#RuntimeFunctions-Eval(codeasString)asDynamic)

> Do not use Eval() outside of the main() function as it can cause unexpected bugs and crashes

Not sure I completely understand the restriction, what do they mean when they say "running outside of main"?

Comment: To add to @U.Mitic answer, you can get more info here : https://sdkdocs.roku.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#RuntimeFunctions-Eval(codeasString)asDynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Roku application has main.brs file ( You can name this file whatever you want as long as it's located under source folder, [Nas Banov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226086/nas-banov) pointed out in the comment below that there is no main.brs requirement) and in it you will have Main() function.
For example Deep linking is implemented by passing parameters to the Main() function etc. Also this is Roku's main thread (you have Main, SceneGraph and Task thread).

So what this:

> Do not use Eval() outside of the main() function as it can cause
>   unexpected bugs and crashes

Actually means is this:

> Do not use Eval outside of main thread as it can cause unexpected bugs
>   and crashes

More on SceneGraph Threads :
https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/SceneGraph+Threads

Comment: there is no main.brs requirement and entry point does not have to be `main()`. +1 on the rest

Comment: @NasBanov Thanks for bringing that up! I know that I can name "main.brs" file whatever I want as long as it's under source directory but can You please elaborate on what do You mean by "entry point does not have to be main()"? I thought that every Roku app has do have Sub Main() ---function content--- End Sub so it could run? Sure I can call another function from the Main() one but I have a feeling that that's not want You meant. Thanks!

Comment: There are different entry points, see https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Development+Environment+Overview#DevelopmentEnvironmentOverview-EntryPoints . E.g. `RunUserInterface()` has the same meaning as `main()`